# Failing to create OpenGL swap texture for Oculus Rift

Tags: c++, opengl, oculus

I'm trying to setup my first `C/C++` Oculus Rift project using the `Oculus SDK for Windows (8.0.0)` in an `OpenGL` context, but I can't achieve to make it run properly.

Whenever I try to compile the provided DirectX samples it fully works, but when I try to compile anything relative to OpenGL it fail with somewhat the same texture problem.

If I try to compile and run the provided OculusRommTiny(GL) it returns a "Failed to create texture" and exit.

And, when I try to compile my own work, the `ovr_CreateSwapTextureSetGL` function always returns `false`.

Here are few useful informations (I guess) :

- I'm on **Windows 8.1**
- I'm using the Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
- My project return returns **OpenGL 4.5 is detected**
  *(it returns 4.3 if I let it switch to the integrated graphic card. Yes it's a laptop with a dedicated graphic card and an integrated graphic card)*
- I use the **8.0.0 Oculus C SDK** *(I tried with the 7.0.0 and I had the same results)*
- I use the **8.0.0 Oculus Runtime** *(but I didn't tried with another one yet)*
- I use the **Debug HMD** mode (I tried all debug settings in the Configur Service part of the runtime with the same result) because I don't have access to my Oculus Rift yet.

Here is an extract of my code relative to the problem :

```
if (OVR_SUCCESS(ovr_CreateSwapTextureSetGL(session, GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8, bufferSize.w, bufferSize.h, &pTextureSet)))
{
    /*for (int i = 0; i < pTextureSet->TextureCount; ++i)
    { ... }*/
    std::cout << "OK, keep going..." << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "ERROR: failed creating swap texture" << std::endl;
    ovr_Destroy(session);
    ovr_Shutdown();
    return false;
}
```

Do you have any clue on how to bypass this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you find the correct solution here? Im stuck on the same thing

Comment: Unfortunately no. At the moment I'm still unable to compile any GL projects for Oculus on my laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OculusRommTiny(GL) should work. The problem could be the laptop GPU. This type of configuration with two GPU, "Optimus" for Nvidia and "Switchable graphics" for AMD is very common on laptops and is not supported and won't work most of the time.

On some specific laptops it's possible to disable the integrated GPU in the BIOS, so try that if you can.

Quote from the Oculus [forum](https://forums.oculus.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=26029):

> GPUs below Nvidia GTX 600 series or AMD Radeon HD 7000 series are not
>   supported. In addition, laptops typically are not supported well or at
>   all (especially if they include Nvidia Optimus or AMD Switchable
>   Graphics).

Comment: I saw this post on the forum, but as the DirectX part were working correctly, I was hoping for a different problem. Unfortunately I fear that you are right... And thus I'm stuck using SDK pre 7.0.0 or DirectX which isn't my goal. Thank you